# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' while using highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to implement a line chart using highcharts, in which **I want to color specific points.**

So I am using following statement.

```
JSON.parse("[{x: 1,y: 0},{x:2,y:5,marker:{fillColor:'red'}},{x:3,y:8}]");
```

to color the point (2,5) as red.

But, it is showing error as `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'`

Comment: Note: If the `String` of JSON is actually literal like that, you can skip the `JSON.parse()` and just use [JavaScript literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals) for an `Array` of `Object`s.

Comment: A simpler way to reproduce is just `{a:[]}`

Comment: BTW, there is JSON5 library that can parse that object string as valid JSON5: https://github.com/aseemk/json5

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Valid JSON strings ***require*** the property names to be quoted.

This can be corrected by quoting the property names like below:

```
JSON.parse('[{"x": 1, "y": 0}, {"x":2, "y":5, "marker": {"fillColor":"red"}}, {"x":3, "y":8}]');
```

Comment: its also worth noting that any string values also require double quotes rather than single quotes.  That just caught me out aswell as the property names

Comment: in my case, I must double quote inside and single quotes outside.

Answer (score 3):

As it was said earlier JSON object names must to be quoted. So JSON.parse will parse only that string, valid JSON.

But if you can't for any reason change format of your string you can also parse it using `eval` function which can accept your syntax. But **be careful**! That's pretty good way for exploit.