# JavaScript array from string-array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string `"[{x: 10, y: 20}, {x: 80, y:30}]"`
How to get array from this string?
I need to get `[{x: 10, y: 20}, {x: 80, y: 30}]` (a js array)

If i use Array.from() then i got an array with symbols.

Comment: https://dev.to/amitkhonde/eval-is-evil-why-we-should-not-use-eval-in-javascript-1lbh

Comment: `JSON.parse()` would be the way to go, but your string isn't valid JSON as the object's properties aren't strings (eg: `x: 10` should be `"x": 10`). Do you control where this string comes from? If so, you should consider making it a valid JSON string

Comment: but you really really really shouldn't do it, especially using user input. unless you want to discover the wonderful world of ~hacking~ being hacked

Comment: yes json comes from server

Comment: Fix whatever generates this "json" that is not json

Comment: Related: [Parsing "relaxed" JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9637517)

Comment: @f1f1stashka if you solved with using ```eval``` that is not safe way

Comment: You can get the answer below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699216/6896008